# Is the Docker engine installed on the server or client?

Tags: docker

Is the Docker engine installed on the server to build off of the images it receives and then runs the containers that are built from it or is the engine installed on the client and then the building of images into containers is done there? Is the Docker engine installed on both the client and server and does different actions on each side?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by server and client here. Docker itself also consists of a client (basically the CLI) and a server.

Comment: I meant if you have machine A where you build the code and machine B (server) where you host the code, will they both need to have docker engine installed? would it be correct to say machine A uses Docker to build out images and then pushes them to Docker hub and then machine B pulls the images and then runs them as containers?

Comment: It is up to you on which machine you do what. But a separation as suggested makes probably the most sense. You will need docker then on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Engine is responsible for building, pulling, pushing the image and then running them as container. Docker Engine is installed on the server side and the client side just consist of the CLI used for issuing commands to Docker Engine. The Client uses Rest API to issue commands to server.

In your case both Machine A and Machine B will have Docker Engine. You will need the Docker Engine on Machine A to build the image and then push it to a repository (like Dockerhub). On Machine B you will need Docker Engine to pull the image and then create containers from it.